# Can Shape Water be used to hurt Vampires?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, combat, cantrips

[Shape Water](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/shape-water)  Says:

> You instantaneously move or otherwise change the flow of the water as you direct, up to 5 feet in any direction. **This movement doesn’t have enough force to cause damage.**

[Vampire - Monster](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/vampire) Says:

> Vampire Weaknesses... ... **Harmed by Running Water.** The vampire takes 20 acid damage if it ends its turn in running water.

Does the specific weakness of Vampires, overrule the section in shape of water where it says "not enough force to cause damage"
Can shape water be used to harm a vampire, assuming there is water around to shape? (in a barrel or something.)

Note:  Official WotC rules only please, no UA.

Comment: Very related on [What is considered running water for the vampire's weakness?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/163767/what-is-considered-running-water-for-the-vampires-weakness)

Comment: Is it *holy* water?  If you get a cleric to bless it for you first, you might have something there.  Sort of the D&D equivalent of that scene in *From Dusk Till Dawn* with the super-soakers...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### Only if you use it to create running water

The movement of the water itself is instantaneous, so is unlikely to count as running, and more specifically the vampire has to **end its turn** in the running water, which this spell can't do.

However if you put the water up a height so it slowly dribbled and formed a thin stream that the vampire for some reason stood in, then a generous DM might rule it as running water.

Essentially if you creatively make running water then the running water can hurt the vampire, but the spell itself cannot.

Comment: Can you support that a finite amount of water falling is the same as running water? I mean, of course a DM can rule it as that, but what would help them in making that ruling beyond opinion?

Comment: @NautArch not really, that's why I said generous DM, and 'might'

Comment: That isn't exactly a supported answer, though.

Comment: @NautArch I think that's a bit nitpicking. DM rulings are kind of the point of D&D. If the DM rules in the way I say they might then the answer is perfectly valid. If running water is created by the spell then it will act as running water, that's unambiguous, and including a suggestion of how that may happen shouldn't exactly be seen as a negative. The rest of the answer is rule based.

Comment: DM ruling answers should be supported by game play seen or experienced. Just saying "yeah, sure, why not" isn't really helpful. Of course a DM can make any ruling, but an answer that suggests a ruling should go into the details of how that ruling went.

Comment: Strange I have to cite my options for DM rulings but another answer claims a DM is entirely unable to make a certain ruling and gets no grief.

Comment: All running water has a finite amount available.  It's just usually a large finite amount.  I'm reading a book now by a hiker who talked about a stream near camp when she went to bed but it was dry in the morning--it was fed by snowmelt and without the sunshine the snow wasn't melting.

Comment: @SeriousBri, No, that answer does not say a DM **can't** rule that way. It simply argues that the common term *running water* does not mean "any moving water." As the rules say that you're supposed to go with the common meaning of the term, their Answer seems better supported than yours. Thus it makes sense to ask you to try to add more support to your Answer, like maybe the fact that you've seen this used in practice and it worked well.

Comment: +1 DM discretion aside, interpreting "running water" to refer to any continuous stream of water while it's flowing seems totally normal. When I say my nose is running I don't mean there's some permanent flowing body of unlimited snot, I mean there's a stream of snot flowing from my nose right now.

Answer (score 31):

### "Running water" doesn't simply mean water that is moving at the moment.

"Running water" as a term specifically refers to rivers and streams, not just water that happens to be in motion.  A thrown water bottle is not 'running water', nor is a small continuous leak from a water pipe.

Today we more commonly use the term 'running water' to mean indoor plumbing, but whether a vampire can safely pass through an active sprinkler system or be harmed by a firehose is beyond the scope of the discussion here. In the context of a quasi-medieval world, 'running water' means something like a creek.

So in most cases, *shape water* probably can't produce anything that would be harmful to a vampire -- *potentially*, if you were close to a river, you could redirect some of the flow of water slightly beyond the banks to engulf a vampire (per the "change the flow of the water as you direct" clause), but it would be up to the DM to determine whether that counts or if you're just pulling a single lump of water out of the river, in which case that ball of water would not have a flow and would mean nothing more to the vampire than dumping out a bucket over its head. In either case, water out of a barrel would *definitely* not count as running water, even if you got it to move in the short term.

Historically, most of the vampiric weaknesses are things seen as sources of purity and cleansing -- sunlight, running water, salt, garlic, fire, and holy water were all associated with purifying the unclean or just being inherently pure. Running water in specific was often associated with the holy rite of baptism, in addition to being where you go to clean everything from your clothes to your body. (If garlic and salt seem strange on that list, remember that before refrigeration, salt was a preservative, and strong spices were often used to cover the taste of meat that was starting to go rancid. This was several centuries prior to germ theory, so covering up the taste and smell was seen as *basically* the same thing as actually purifying the food.)

D&D doesn't directly operate on historical intent, but it seems to me that knowing why this specific collection of relatively random things are meaningful to a vampire should give us insight into what does and doesn't count.

Comment: Is this supported by any actual rules? A DM can definitely not rule something as running water? That's quite a claim.

Comment: Obviously a DM can rule however they want to; that's so core to the game that it hardly bears mentioning. Since the game does not define "running water", we have to default to the standard english use of the phrase, which has a specific meaning as I have described here.

Comment: (At least, the standard english use of the phrase before household plumbing became commonplace.)

Comment: @DarthPseudonym: I agree with you most of this. Re: Vampire weakness; the original vampires (i.e. from Eastern European lore, not Stoker) were disease bearers (and/or disease explanations). Thus, vampire weaknesses tend to be things that ward off diseases and maladies(garlic is anti-microbial, sunlight can improve immune response, silver is anti-biotic, salt can stop food from spoiling which can  cause food poisoning if eaten) or stop their spread (e.g. burning bodies to prevent the spread of plague). In this pattern, running water fits because it is saf*er* to drink from than stagnant water.

Comment: @sharur That analysis doesn't really hold up to actual vampire lore, which includes a lot of much more bizarre stuff, like scattering seeds that the vampire will feel compelled to count (thus disabling them until dawn), being driven away by twins wearing their shirts backwards, or being terrified of rowan wood. It's much more likely that we're just looking at a collection of "pure things" and trying to find patterns, while the people at the time were just gesturing vaguely in the direction of "stuff that evil beings probably don't like".

Comment: Scattering seeds? well that explains this guy moreso than just a bad pun https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Count_(character)

Comment: I'm pretty sure the Count is just a pun on the fact that he counts things, and vampiric arithmomania is just a happy coincidence.

Comment: -1 Since it seems to me that "running water" refers to any continuous stream of water while it's flowing... when water comes out of my faucet it's "running water".

Comment: Well, I did specifically say that home plumbing borrowed the term. All I can say is the OED says it's "water taken from a flowing stream or river", and secondarily, home plumbing as distinct from like pulling buckets out of a well.  I've never heard of, say, a leaky bucket being referred to as 'running water'.

Answer (score 4):

#### No, the vampire cannot end its turn in water that is being moved by *shape water*.

*Shape water* dictates that it moves water *instantaneously*. This indicates that a vampire could not end its turn in water that is moving via *shape water*, since the water moves instantaneously. Water that moves instantaneously also cannot be said to be “running” in any meaningful sense.

Comment: The header here sounds like it's saying something different from your actual answer. Your text is saying that *shape water* doesn't cause the water to be running, but the header sounds like the vampire finds shaped water impossible to remain in.

Comment: @DarthPseudonym *Moving*. The vampire cannot end its turn in water that is *moving* by means of *shape water*, since *shape water* transports the water instantaneously from one point to another.

Comment: Right, I can see what you meant, I'm just saying at first glance it gives a very wrong impression of what you're saying.

Comment: @DarthPseudonym Is that header a bit more clear?

Comment: No, because the header says a vampire is restricted from entering water, not that *shape water* fails to create a hazard.  It reads as "if you use *shape water*, you create a zone that a vampire cannot end its turn in".

Comment: @DarthPseudonym I don't think you're interpreting "cannot" correctly. Vampires can end their turn in running water. (It causes them damage.)

Comment: I know what the rules are; I'm trying to improve an answer by alerting the poster to a misleading headline.

Comment: Agreed that the header is confusing. I'd go with something like "no, because it's impossible for a vampire to end its turn in water that is being moved by shape water."

Comment: @Kat That doesn't fix anything. The problem is that starting with "the vampire can't" makes it sound like we're discussing a restriction on the vampire's actions, where the focus *should* be on "the water isn't moving".  It needs to say something like "no, because the water is not moving at the end of the vampire's turn".

Comment: @DarthPseudonym Or "No, the water affected by the spell is not moving during the vampire's turn"